# Unpack assignment vs chained assignment

Tags: python, python-2.7

Say you need to initialize two variables to None.
**Following [Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) which way should be used (and why)?**
*(assuming the following methods are your choices)*

---

**Unpack assignment**

```
a, b = None, None  # Explicit
```

or
**Chained assignment**

```
a = b = None # faster. Still readable (perhaps less explicit than unpack?)
```

---

The notion of "explicit is better" seems like it could apply in either case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Unpack assignment vs chained assignment

> ```
> a, b = None, None  # Explicit
> ```

The above *is* explicit. It explicitly and unnecessarily creates an extra data structure:

```
a, b = None, None   
#makes (None, None) before unpacking and giving to a and b
```

Instead, do the chained assignment. That also *explicitly* does what you want, without doing anything unnecessary. I consider it an elegant application of the language:

```
a = b = None
```

If you feel the above, in its own unique context, is too dense to be readable, you can also do this without any shame whatsoever:

```
a = None
b = None
```

#### disassembly, Python 2 and 3:

```
import dis

def tupleunpack():
    a, b = None, None

def chainedassignment():
    a = b = None

def multiline():
    a = None
    b = None

>>> dis.dis(tupleunpack)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ((None, None))
              3 UNPACK_SEQUENCE          2
              6 STORE_FAST               0 (a)
              9 STORE_FAST               1 (b)
             12 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             15 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis(chainedassignment)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              3 DUP_TOP
              4 STORE_FAST               0 (a)
              7 STORE_FAST               1 (b)
             10 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             13 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis(multiline)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              3 STORE_FAST               0 (a)

  3           6 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              9 STORE_FAST               1 (b)
             12 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             15 RETURN_VALUE
```

Disassembly demonstrates that tuple unpacking creates an unnecessary data struction.
Going multiline unnecessarily loads None twice. Chained assignment is preferable in terms of eliminating unnecessary processes.

#### Performance, Python 3:

Tuple unpacking also seems to generally take slightly more time:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.repeat(tupleunpack)
[0.09981771527421301, 0.10060130717376126, 0.10003051661827556]
>>> timeit.repeat(chainedassignment)
[0.09882977371520241, 0.0981032306866183, 0.0982816216005773]
>>> timeit.repeat(multiline)
[0.09878721344639274, 0.09834682031024045, 0.09854603858978805]
```

#### Zen to justify code?

Also, the Zen of Python describes the principles in tension under which the Python language evolved. Thus I'm always wary, however, when people use it to justify code. Instead of trying to get specific direction from a collection of Zen aphorisms, do the semantically correct things explicitly provided for in the language (such as, in this case, the chained assignment.)

Comment: Reading your latest update, I present you with the argument in favor of Zen that says the chained assignment is explicit and therefor IS Zen!  At least I am beginning to think so.